# Отслеживание состояния сети

Tags: java, android, сеть

Есть задача: выполнять некие запросы на сервер когда появляется подключение к интернету! Первая идея - сделать `BroadcastReceiver` который слушает `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`, где то я читал что этот интент уже `Deprected`  но щас не могу найти по этому поводу инфо, если кто то знает где можно посмотреть - дайте ссылочку. Вопрос, стоит ли использовать этот интент у себя в приложении или есть еще какие то альтернативные способы для выполнения задач при появлении сети.
З.Ы.  `GcmNetworkManager` не предлагать))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ссылка на документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION). Он не deprecated, и отлично работает.
Альтернативы может и есть, например каждую секунду пинговать, но смысла в них не вижу, т. к. этот способ работает, как и раньше

Comment: вот меня это и сбыло с толку щас я смотрел документацию  и там все ок, а до этого, тоже вроде в офф.доках видел что deprecated. Может то на 7 версии... Спасибо!